# Web Deploy Failure: User Unauthorized

Tags: visual-studio-2015, publish, webdeploy

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition on my local machine.  This issue occurs when I Build>Publish with the credentials I get pulled off of my Windows Server 2012 R2 which runs Parallel Plesk 12.5.  I exported the web deploy settings from Plesk. So all the credentials entered should be correct.

When I click the publish button I get the following error in this image:

[image: error message img]

How do I correct this error? I feel like there has to be something misconfigured on my server to be causing this issue.

**Update**:In the publish menu I have been able to validate the connection where the green checkmark pops up now. In IIS, I added my user to the site I was having trouble with. I still get the same error in the image tho when I actually click publish. Any other ideas? I am guessing i need to change a thing or two in IIS to fully correct the problem.

**Update 2**: This update is in reference to the post left by @Jan Remunda below. I have gone through the checklist. Here are my results:

*I went in to the Roles and Features Wizard and confirmed that Management Service is installed.
*I followed the link and installed the entire package of feature for Web Deploy.
*In IIS Manager, I went to my site, gamepaduniverse.com, and added the user. Restarted computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for right behavior of this feature you have to do few steps

- install Web Deploy IIS extension (http://www.microsoft.com/cs-cz/download/details.aspx?id=43717) and install entire IIS Deployment handler feature and IIS Manager UI Module (see bellow)
- install web server management service and ensure that is running (set automatic start on services panel).
- set manager permissions to user that are you using for deployment in Site > IIS Manager permissions
- either set this user as local administrator or setup rights to deploy in Management Service Delegation on server
- if you want to use NTLM authentication instead of basic you must add some config to registers and restart management service

  reg add
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server /v WindowsAuthenticationEnabled /t
  REG_DWORD /d 1

IIS Management service installation
[image: IIS Management service installation]

Web Deploy installation
[image: Web deploy installation]

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to published several times before, however one day I encountered this error when using Web Deploy to an Azure Website using an imported publish profile.

On the prompt it's saying I was connected but not authorized (#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED) I had the correct username and password (from my publish profile) as confirmed when I clicked on "Validate Connection"

What worked for me was put in the password string and publish/preview it directly instead of click on validate connection. Hope this helps